# Problem creating block diagram using TikZ in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am running into a stupid problem. I can't seem to connect the last two boxes. And also I want to have |.| in one of the boxes but I don't know how it's done. Can somebody help me with this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,latexsym,upref} %stmaryrd
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                quotes}
\begin{document}

\resizebox{16cm}{2cm}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance = 12mm,
        start chain = A going right,
     block/.style = {draw, fill=white,
                     text width=#1, minimum height=10mm, align=center,
                     outer sep=0pt, on chain},
     block/.default = 18mm,
 container/.style = {draw, fill=gray!50,
                     inner xsep=2mm, inner ysep=7mm},
                        ]
\node   [block=14mm] {a};    % block name is A-1
\node   [block=12mm] {b};
\node   [block=22mm] {c};
\node   [block=15mm] {d};
\node   [block=22mm] {e};    % block name is A-4
\node   [block=22mm] {f};    % block name is A-6
\node   [block=12mm] {g};
\node   [block=24mm] {h};    % block name is A-8
\node   [block=24mm] {i};    % block name is A-8
%
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node [container, label={[anchor=north]joined},
           fit= (A-5) (A-6)] (container) {};
\draw [-Stealth]
    (A-1) edge  (A-2)    % text on arrow is between " and "
    (A-2) edge  (A-3)
    (A-3) edge  (A-4)
    (A-4) edge  (A-5)
    (A-5) edge  (A-6)
    (A-6) edge  (A-7);
    (A-7) edge (A-8);
    (A-8) edge (A-8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The last block labeled by i has name `A-9`, and if you put semicolons, you'll need to add a new draw command.

Comment: got it! Thanks! And  do you have any idea how I could add modulo bars ( | . | ) in one of the boxes.

Comment: ... or did you mean to put the bars around one letter? If so, around which one?

Answer (score 1):

The last block labeled by i has name `A-9`, and if you put semicolons, you'll need to add a new draw command. I hope I understood your modulo bar request correctly.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,latexsym,upref} %stmaryrd
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                quotes}
\begin{document}

\resizebox{16cm}{2cm}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance = 12mm,
        start chain = A going right,
     block/.style = {draw, fill=white,
                     text width=#1, minimum height=10mm, align=center,
                     outer sep=0pt, on chain},
     block/.default = 18mm,
 container/.style = {draw, fill=gray!50,
                     inner xsep=2mm, inner ysep=7mm},
                        ]
\node   [block=14mm] {a};    % block name is A-1
\node   [block=12mm] {b};
\node   [block=22mm] {c};
\node   [block=15mm] {d};
\node   [block=22mm] {e~$|.|$};    % block name is A-4
\node   [block=22mm] {f};    % block name is A-6
\node   [block=12mm] {g};
\node   [block=24mm] {h};    % block name is A-8
\node   [block=24mm] {i};    % block name is A-9
%
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node [container, label={[anchor=north]joined},
           fit= (A-5) (A-6)] (container) {};
\draw [-Stealth]
    (A-1) edge  (A-2)    % text on arrow is between " and "
    (A-2) edge  (A-3)
    (A-3) edge  (A-4)
    (A-4) edge  (A-5)
    (A-5) edge  (A-6)
    (A-6) edge  (A-7)
    (A-7) edge (A-8)
    (A-8) edge (A-9);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

- the mwe in question is very familiar to me :-)
- you should analyse code, which you use in your mwe .. . then you will observe that name of last node is `A-9` (and not `A-8` as you noted in your mwe)
- for most common size you should select as default size, for example `block/.default=22mm` and only for rest write desired text widths (do you realy need so diferent node size? i would use only `18mm` nad `9mm`, see mwe below)
- math expression you can write in node as in text, for example $|\cdot|$
- *don't use `\resizebox{16cm}{...`. it resize everything in image and with them make it ugly. rather recalculate width of nodes and nodes distances that their sum is 16 cm:

  14mm + 12mm + 22mm + 15mm + 22mm + 22mm +12mm +24mm +24mm + 9x2x(innersep) +8*(node distance)= `318 mm`

  what is almost twioce to long. i suggest to halve all image elements lengths  (see mwe below) and use smaller fonnt size, for example `footnotesize`:

from mwe doesnt follows, that you will add text on arrows between nodes. if this is case, than you can draw them with `join` macro from `chains` library

consider above comments and suggestion, your mwe become:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amscd,amssymb,latexsym,upref} %stmaryrd
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                fit,
                quotes}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 7mm,
        start chain = A going right,
     block/.style = {draw, fill=white,
                     text width=#1, minimum height=10mm, align=center,
                     font=\footnotesize, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=0pt,
                     on chain, join=by -Stealth},
     block/.default = 12mm,
 container/.style = {draw, fill=gray!50,
                     inner xsep=2mm, inner ysep=7mm},
                        ]
\node   [block=6mm] {a};    % block name is A-1
\node   [block=6mm] {b};
\node   [block]     {$|\cdot|$};
\node   [block=6mm] {d};
\node   [block]     {e};    % block name is A-4
\node   [block]     {f};    % block name is A-6
\node   [block=6mm] {g};
\node   [block]     {h};
\node   [block]     {i};    % block name is A-9
%
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node [container, label={[anchor=north]joined},
           fit= (A-5) (A-6)] (container) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*note*: if you like to label arrows between node, than you should remove `join` option from block style definition and to image add:

```
\draw [-Stealth]
    (A-1) edge ["$\alpha$"]    (A-2) 
    (A-2) edge ["$\beta$"]     (A-3)
    (A-3) edge ["$\gamma$"]    (A-4)
    (A-4) edge ["$\epsilon$"]  (A-5)
    (A-5) edge ["$\zeta$"]     (A-6)
    (A-6) edge ["$\theta$"]    (A-7)
    (A-7) edge ["$\iota$"]     (A-8)
    (A-8) edge ["$\kappa$"]    (A-9);
```

and to image options add:

```
every edge quote/.append style = {font=\footnotesize}
```

[image]

drawing images require a lot of patient, accuracy and time ...